# Did Jawaharlal Nehru send a plane to Indore to bring back a pack of cigarettes?

Tags: india, cigarettes

There has been this claim going around Twitter talking about the former Prime Minister of India, Jawaharlal Nehru and his need for cigarettes.

For example, Twitter user @RishBagree [wrote](https://twitter.com/rishibagree/status/1061974152771334145):

> Jawaharlal Nehru was very fond of smoking. His favorite brand was 555 Cigarette. One time he was at visit of Bhopal and he forget to bring cigarettes with him & also didn't get this brand in Bhopal.
> Then he send a airplane to bring his brand from Bhopal to Indore.

He cites the [website of the Governor of Madhya Pradesh](http://governor.mp.gov.in/Guvs_Anecdotes.aspx):

> On a visit of Jawahar Lal Nehru to Bhopal, the Raj Bhavan staff realised that the favourite cigarette brand of Nehruji "555" was not available in the Raj Bhavan. Nehruji used to have a cigarette after his meals. The staff immediately sent a plane to Indore for air-lifting Nehruji's favourite pack, which was kept ready at the Indore airport.

I found this amazing. But, when I searched, I found that the [Indore airport was established in 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Ahilya_Bai_Holkar_Airport) and that [Nehru died in 1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jawaharlal_Nehru).

Does this mean the diary entry is false or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm kind of impressed there's a government website in India with the URL "Guvs_Anecdotes" that just lists a bunch of urban legends and anecdotes about former governors

Comment: I am not saying that the story is true or false - that will take far more digging - but your evidence against it seems like a misreading.  "Air services from Indore to Gwalior, Delhi and Mumbai began in July 1948." It was only a runway that was completed in 1966.

Comment: Title doesn't match 2nd quoted claim?!? Who allegedly sent the plane? Nehru himself (title & twatter) or 'that guv'/his staff (2nd claim)? Please differentiate this within the question's text.

Comment: I know, the tweet and the source is different but this is what the tweeter quoted. Misinformation is rampant. @LangLаngС

Comment: Whether des-/mis- or whatnot-info — or mere error – with _how you_ formulate the main/title question _you_ set the frame to answer here. You might keep that 'more open' by phrasing this centered on the cigs, not Nehru; that it seems an established anecdote 'connected to him' (whether it indeed was him ordering the stunt might be a subquestion, unless you already know twatter to be in error)?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose if one finds answer to one, the answer to the other would be there too @LangLаngС

Comment: Maybe the question could be worded in the passive: "Was a plane sent from Bhopal to Indore to fetch a pack of cigarettes for Jawaharlal Nehru?" Who gave the order doesn't seem to be important to the story.

Comment: That's a short spin away from "On the way back, will you please pick up some State Express 555?"

Comment: You made me . That's gotta mean something

Comment: This question should be removed as the cited claim cannot be verified - the linked [website of the Governor of Madhya Pradesh](http://governor.mp.gov.in/Guvs_Anecdotes.aspx) doesn't have this "incident" listed in its page at all.